# ttyACM0 no such file or directory On Ubunutu 14.04

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, usb, linux

I have an Arduino Uno which communicated with the computer (Ubunutu 14.04) fine till 6 days ago (I assume some software update is to blame).

Now when trying to upload I get

processing.app.SerialNotFoundException: Serial port '/dev/ttyACM0' not found. Did you select the right one from the Tools > Serial Port menu?   at processing.app.Serial.(Serial.java:191)    at processing.app.Serial.(Serial.java:77)     at processing.app.debug.Uploader.flushSerialBuffer(Uploader.java:77)    at processing.app.debug.AvrdudeUploader.uploadViaBootloader(AvrdudeUploader.java:175)   at processing.app.debug.AvrdudeUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(AvrdudeUploader.java:67)     at processing.app.Sketch.upload(Sketch.java:1671)   at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1627)     at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1599)     at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2380)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

When I sudo ls /dev/ttyA*

I get

```
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyA*: No such file or directory
```

So it does not look like a permission issue.

when I lsusb

I get

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So it does not even see the device (which is connected and pulling current).

when I dmesg before and after connecting the Arduino, I don't see anything new.

I tried switching USB cables, and switching USB ports on the machine (both ports work with a mouse), but in vain.

What went wrong and how do I fix it ?

Thanks,
David.

Comment: Can you try the Arduino on someone else's computer?

Comment: @Majenko I tried on my wife's Mac and it didn't work, but I only installed the software on that machine for the purpose of the troubleshooting, so I still have hope that I did something wrong on it; I say "hope" because currently the leading options I see are: 1) something bad happened to the USB controller, 2) two faulty cables (that one is hard to believe)

Comment: Does the power light illuminate?  Does the LED on pin 13 blink a couple of times when you first connect it?

Comment: @Majenko even better - there was a program on it (which my kid wrote at the beginning of the week); when we plug the arduino it still runs ...

Comment: The next step would be to try to access the USB comm chip out of band. You wouldn't happen to have a AVR ISP programmer or a second, working Arduino, would you?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'll get my hands on a second arduino on Sunday. What should I do then ?

Comment: Follow the [ArduinoISP tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) and hook it up to the 6-pin connector near the small chip (Atmega16U2) closest to the USB connector, then use avrdude to try and communicate with the chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it sounds like there is an issue with the ATMega(8/16)U2 chip or its surroundings.  It might just need its firmware refreshing (which can be done with another Arduino as a programmer) or it might be plain dead.

Another possibility is the USB socket itself.  I have two UNOs, one which is perfectly fine, and one where I need to hold the cable at just the right angle for it to connect properly.  You can try using a fine needle to try and raise the four metal strips in the USB connector a fraction to make better contact.